# Forcing Nexus 5 to charge wirelessly even when USB device connected

Tags: nexus-5, wireless-charging

Is there some method to make wireless charging take priority over wired (USB) charging? I have a device that has to be plugged in to the micro-USB port of the Nexus, and it is preventing wireless charging from occurring. The device only draws power from the USB, but still wireless charging stops the moment it is plugged in.

Google has not been helpful so far. There seem to be [other phones](http://www.wpcentral.com/supercharge-nokia-lumia-920-wireless-wired-charging) whose wired charging stops when placed on a wireless charger, but apparently not the Nexus (nor have I been able to find a user's manual which states which one takes priority).

There doesn't seem to be any visible setting in Android. Any clues? Maybe some App which can set the charging priority? Completely disabling USB charging is also fine, as long as the USB can still supply power to connected devices (rooting is not an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell  [and from links like this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-5/363516-wireless-charging-usb-same-time-no.html) and also  [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/nexus4-double-charging-t2221237) (for different devices obviously) it seems that once the USB is plugged in that is what will charge the device, and the [wireless-charging](/questions/tagged/wireless-charging) is disabled.

> The Nexus 4 has two main power circuits: 1) Battery Connector & Charging Circuit & 2) Wireless Charging GEN2 Circuit. These two work together with internal battery protection circuit as well. There are many controls going on while charging, such as current sensors, thermal sensors, voltage reference and voltage input detection. So basically it has been thought to avoid any problem if you happen to connect both charging supplies at the same time, as only one will act as the charger, and as far as I can understand the logic of it, it’s the USB charging that has priority over wireless charging.

Comment: Thanks for the links. So it seems that just plugging in anything to the USB port (not a charger but even something that draws power from the port) disables wireless charging. That's really a pity, since there would be no way to bypass this "feature" without actually modifying the hardware.